# Как привести List<Task> к Task[]?

Tags: c#

Как я могу привести список тасков к массиву? Решил изначально сделать списком, чтобы пользоваться методом Add(), но теперь не могу привести список к массиву

```
public void Purge(IEnumerable<string> clearList)
{
    List<Task> tasks1 = new List<Task> { };
    
    foreach (string i in clearList)
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(() => deleteAllIn(i));
        tasks1.Add(t);
    }

    Task[] tasks = (Task[])(from i in tasks1 select i);// <--- пробовал так

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: [.ToArray()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Очень просто как любой IEnumerable к массиву  .ToArray()

Answer (score 7):

В качестве альтернативного варианта, имеет смысл не дожидаться списка тасков синхронно — это чревато deadlock-ом (да и блокировать поток для ожидания не стоит). Попробуйте асинхронное ожидание:

```
public Task PurgeAsync(IEnumerable<string> clearList) =>
    Task.WhenAll(
        clearList.Select(i =>
            Task.Run(() =>
                deleteAllIn(i))));
```

Не забудьте за-`await`-ить результат вызова там, где вы его вызываете.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, почему в коде автора может возникнуть deadlock?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko зависит от того, в каком потоке запускается код и что делает код внутри таска. Если это UI поток и внутри таска где либо идет синхронное обращение к UI потоку, то синхронное ожидание `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` приведет к дедлоку.

Comment: А если код в таске не обращается к UI, нужно ли асинхронное ожидание внутри этого таска? Метод `Purge()` будет, вызываться в другом таске, в котором помимо него будут еще другие манипуляции, думал этот главный запускать асинхронно. Плохо разбираюсь в асинхронности, хотел бы уточнить

Comment: @Nonameguy: Смотрите, это большая тема. Если у вас есть ожидание какой-то реально асинхронной операции (например, чтение данных из интернета), то лучше делать это асинхронно, чтобы не занимать поток (потоки — ценный ресурс). Если же это просто какая-то медленная операция (обработка в памяти данных, например), то выгружать её в другой поток через `Task.Run` обычно нет особого смысла, т. к. всё равно какой-то поток будет занят. В вашем случае, однако, выгрузка в другой поток через `Task.Run` имеет смысл, чтобы выполнить несколько заданий параллельно.

Comment: Интересно, почему для WhenAll сделали перегрузку с IEnumerable, а для WaitAll - нет 

Comment: @Grundy: Думаю, раз асинхронное ожидание не приветствуется, необходимости в дальнейшем развитии API не было

Answer (score 3):

Запускать неизвестное (или вы точно знаете что в коллекции никогда не будет много-много элементов?) количество задач не очень хорошо.

Если у Вас CPU-bound операция, тогда для распределения задачи по ядрам вам поможет `Parallel.ForEach`

```
public void Purge(IEnumerable<string> clearList)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(clearList, i => deleteAllIn(i));
}
```

А если у Вас работа с одним физическим диском, нет никакого смысла её выполнять параллельно. Это даже может снизить производительность.
Но очень даже есть смысл выполнять её асинхронно. Но, увы асинхронного удаления файлов нет в .Net. Поэтому просто цикл выполняющийся не в GUI-потоке это оптимальное решение.

Comment: Хочу написать приложение для очистки временных файлов, однако пользователь может сам выбирать через чекбоксы какие директории он хочет очистить, ваш метод подойдет? Таск запускает поток с максимальным приоритетом, так хочу добиться высокой скорости очистки, подойдет ли `Parallel` лучше в этой ситуации?

Comment: Вообщем-то нет. Не подойдёт. И ваш изначальный тоже. И @VladD. Работу с диском нет особого смысла параллелить. Если несколько физ.дисков, вот только тогда есть смысл распределить по каждому.

Comment: Очень правильное замечание, насколько я знаю, работа с дисками идёт последовательно, в параллелизации нет особого смысла. Разве что дело идёт о разных физических (не логических) дисках.